# Avoiding repetition of queries with Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I am a python noob and this question may be trivial. So go easy on me.

Part of this app makes a db query to return all records in the tables. Everything works as expected however, I want to output the results from multiple queries in a flask template whilst avoiding repeating myself in order to keep the code as DRY as possible.

**total_products = Product.query.all()** and **total_users = User.query.all()**

```
@main_bp.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    total_products = Product.query.all()
    total_users = User.query.all()
    return render_template('dashboard.jinja2', template='dashboard-template', 
                            total_products=total_products, total_users=total_users)
```

```
@main_bp.route('/dashboard', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def dashboard():
    total_products = Product.query.all()
    total_users = User.query.all()
    flash('You were successfully logged in.')
    return render_template('dashboard.jinja2', template='dashboard-template',
                           current_user=current_user, total_products=total_products,
                           total_users=total_users)
```

An ideal pythonic way to go about this would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: General comment re: "DRY": I don't see any problem with the code as written. You have already done 99% of keeping things DRY by using SQLAlchemy rather than writing out twenty lines of code to grab a connection, run the SQL, and serialize the results in each view. It's good to think about code quality, but it's easy to get too wrapped up in these things, and trying to make things DRY can end up causing more pain later on. For more, I recommend this article: https://www.sandimetz.com/blog/2016/1/20/the-wrong-abstraction

Comment: 'duplication is far cheaper than the wrong abstraction' (From your recommendation)
This makes sense. Thanks @MarkHildreth